# @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap multi item slider

Tags: angular2-template

I have installed a package @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap for my angular project, I already implemented the carousel by it, but I need a multi-item carousel, can anybody suggest whether I can achieve it by this package or not, please suggest some tutorials.

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0):

In some research, I have not found that ng-bootstrap has a function for this at this time--Please correct me if I'm wrong.

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2083

If I ammm correct, since you already have the bootstrap dependency, I would import the 3 required js dependencies (popper, jquery, bootstrap.min.js)

and attempt to use something like this? (Is this what you are talking about?)
https://www.codeply.com/go/HDu8lT7NxJ